# SQL Query To show employee attendance and their absence with null values

Tags: sql

I want to write a query to show the employee's attendance and absence for a month. I have two tables: Emp and Checkinout

```
emp table: Emp_ID, Name
Checkinout: ID, Emp_ID_Fk, checkin, checkout
```

I want result like this:

```
date, emp.name, checkin, checkout
2019-10-17, John, 2019-10-17, 2019-10-17
2019-10-18, John , null , null <- Absent
2019-10-19, John, 2019-10-19, 2019-10-19
2019-10-17, Mike,2019-10-17, 2019-10-17
2019-10-18, Mike, 2019-10-18,2019-10-18
2019-10-19, Mike , null, null <- absent
```

this is what I cam up with:

```
with dated as (
select  distinct convert(varchar,checkin,112) Day_Per_Month
from checkinout
where month(checkin) =10)

select convert(date,Day_Per_Month) as Date, emp.name as Employee_Name
from dated 
left join checkinout on convert(varchar,checkin, 112) = Day_Per_Month 
left join emp on emp.emp_id = checkinout.Emp_ID_Fk
```

Note: when `emp` does not checkin, the system does not insert any record in the checkinout table.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and you are using non-standard date functions). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However you don't specified any DBMS so I tried with *Sql Server 2012*

- First you don't have entry in CheckInOut table for absent employee so you need to generate relevant date for that. So, by using **CTE** you can do that as shown in answer.
  which give you date from `'2019-10-17` to `'2019-10-20` you can change it as your requirement.
- By using **CASE** and **SUB QUERY** you can filter out with employee is present on particular date.
- Finally by using **JOIN** (here I use old join because there is no relationship between data cte and employee) you can pullout your desired output.

try below Query:

```
;With Cte_Date AS
(
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,'2019-10-17') AS MonthDate
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(dd,+1,MonthDate) AS MonthDate FROM Cte_Date WHERE MonthDate<=CONVERT(DATE,'2019-10-19')
)

SELECT e.Emp_Id,
e.Name,
d.MonthDate,
CASE WHEN  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CheckInOut AS c WHERE c.CheckIn=d.MonthDate AND c.Emp_Id=e.Emp_Id) THEN d.MonthDate ELSE NULL END AS CheckIn,
CASE WHEN  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CheckInOut AS c WHERE c.CheckOut=d.MonthDate AND c.Emp_Id=e.Emp_Id) THEN d.MonthDate ELSE NULL END AS CheckOut
FROM Cte_Date AS d, Employee AS e
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=3068703ee931f986a86cbe045869b992)

Note:*Syntax may differ based on your DBMS*

Comment: what is the need for OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0); ?

Comment: Oh ,MAXRECURSION value equal to 0 means that no limit is applied to the recursion level

Comment: it's correct way, but I used with dated as (
select  distinct convert(varchar,checkin,112) Day_Per_Month
from checkinout
where month(checkin) =10) : the reason for that to exclude weekends!  Thanks again!